# Как округлить число после запятой?

Tags: javascript, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Есть число - `0.0000049999999999999996`
Как его можно округлить до `0.000005`?

Comment: Правильный ответ - "никак нельзя". `0.000005` не представляется точно в вещественных числах. Если вы хотите напечатать строку-результат "округлённый до шести знаков после запятой", то `x.toFixed(6)`. Но это именно строка, не число в памяти компьютера.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy действительно вы правы - в контексте использования ТС (т.е. вне известного контекста) - никак.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `Math.round()`. Но, поскольку эта функция округляет до целого числа, сначала его необходимо домножить до целого, округлить и разделить на число, на которое изначально домножали.

```js
let a = 0.0000049999999999999996;
console.log(Math.round(a * 1000000) / 1000000);
```

Comment: ... и получится у вас `0.000005000000000000000409015270` которое ничем не лучше исходного числа. Суть задачи не в получении округлённого числа (что в данном случае невозможно/бесполезно), а в правильной печати того что есть.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy не понимаю, о чём вы? У меня выводится `0.000005`, проверил также с `0.1 + 0.2` вместо `a`, и всё заработало, вывелось `0.3`.

Comment: @rusgeli, легче сделать так: `Math.round(a / 1e6) * 1e6` (Числа те же, то только в виде литералов)

Comment: @ΝNL993, это правда. Я посчитал, что для других будет нагляднее обычное представление числа, а не научная нотация

Comment: @rusgeli проблема таких чисел в том что бывает непонятно какое кол-во нулей в них (не знаю как у вас, а у меня в глазах плывёт когда я их пытаюсь подсчитать). Поэтому я предпочитаю литералы вместо обычных чисел.

Comment: @rusgeli не сужу вас за это, сам забыл про него :)

Comment: @ΝNL993, Простите, не вам адресовал этот комментарий:)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, Вы правы, суть задачи в правильной печати, с чем этот код справляется. Признаю, забыл о методе toFixed(), который эффективнее и проще в данной ситуации. На точность я не претендовал подобным решением.

Comment: @ΝNL993 дело в том, что в JS числа это (емнип) double - 64byte-float по стандарту IEEE-754. Так вот прикол в том, что `0.000005` никак точно не представимо. Будет либо `0.00000499999...` либо `0.00000500000032...`

Comment: Чуть-чуть не прав - это для 32б. Но для 64б картина аналогична.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```js
console.log(0.0000049999999999999996.toFixed(6))
```

Comment: И `+` поставить, иначе это уже строка...

Comment: `0.0000049999999999999996` - число. Постановка плюса не меняет ничего, а ответ становится сомнительным. Это как в книге по безопасному вождению видишь рекомендацию иконки прикрепить.

Comment: Проверь

`console.log(typeof 0.0000049999999999999996.toFixed(6))`
`console.log(typeof +0.0000049999999999999996.toFixed(6))`

Comment: @ksa лучше было сказать так: `Также используйте унарный оператор \`+\`, чтобы перевести строку в число.`

Comment: Тебе видней "как сказать лучше"...

Answer (score 2):

Простой правильный ответ - "никак нельзя". Как говорит документация -

> JavaScript Numbers are Always 64-bit Floating Point. JavaScript numbers are always stored as double precision floating point numbers, following the international IEEE 754 standard".

`0.000005` не представляется точно в IEEE-754. Под капотом это все равно будет `0.0000050000000000000004090152695701565477293115691281855106353759765625`.

*Представление подсмотрено вот тут - https://baseconvert.com/ieee-754-floating-point*

---

Более сложный ответ - можно, но для этого надо привлекать дополнительные средства (библиотеки и типы данных).

---

Если вы просто хотите напечатать строку-результат "округлённый до шести знаков после запятой", то `x.toFixed(6)`. Но это именно строка, не число в памяти компьютера.

Comment: Правильный ответ - "можно, но с костылями" :))

Comment: @ΝNL993 вы правы. Это общий ответ - не стесняйтесь его сами дополнять! :-)